# Why doesn't Ruby confuse two instance variables in different methods in the same class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Order < ApplicationController

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

So why doesn't Ruby/Rails get confused with the same instance variables in two different methods within the same class?

Comment: Why do you think it should get confused?

Comment: Did you get my answer?

Comment: Did you mean: OrderController ?

Comment: pramod - yes, fotanus - yes I mean OrderController. I just wrote that manually.

Comment: Sergio - Privet! In Java let's say I did something similar, the variable @project would be overwritten with the new value. That doesn't seem to happen with ruby

Answer (score 2):

As a Rails controller, it is invoked when `/new` or `/show` is requested by the browser. For each request a new instance of the controller class is created. So either  `new` or `show` will be executed, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

Because a new instance of the class is created to handle every request.

[EDIT]: if you were to have another method called `Order#do_stuff_with_project`, you could call it from both `Order#show` and `Order#new`, and it could access the `@project` variable. They are simple methods, nothing magical.

Or you can put it this way: by convention both methods are never called on the same controller instance. It's an example of [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Comment: Can you explain more why calling Order#show from Order#new wouldn't override the instance variable @project to a new value? I don't know why but coming from Java, Ruby confuses me

Comment: Sorry for the artificial example, I made a better one.

Comment: Spasiba for your effort to explain Leonid:i understand it can access  '@project' variable but if 'do_stuff_with_project' method had an instance variable let's say '@project = 2'. The value inside '@project' is now changed right? Will it now not overwrite the value we originally assigned '@project' in the 'show' and 'new' method?

Comment: It will be overwritten. `@project` is just like a Java member variable, but it doesn't have to be explicitly declared.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you refresh a page you send a request to your controller there again it is to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods are only called in an [*instance* of an object](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

An instance of an object is when it is loaded / called / initialized, meaning that the instance variable can only be used when that particular object is loaded

Comment: So if I called Order#show inside Order#new the instance variable @project inside 'new' method would cease to exist after it has been loaded and ruby will generate a new instance variable with the value that the instance variable is assigned in the method 'show' ?

Comment: I believe so. I believe it's a matter of [local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) - whereby each method provides its own variable scope. You have to remember that when you render a controller method, the process of rending the view is only for that method; if you wanted to call another method, you'd have a different variable scope I think